# Drawing Image in Canvas Removes Fll Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Before exporting an image from my canvas, I create a new canvas where I do some manipulations (cropping, etc). In this new canvas I fill in the background to blue so that when I export the image the background is blue. However when I put the drawing from the first canvas in, it makes parts of the background transparent. How do I fix this?

Here's the drawing from the first canvas:

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

But I get the following:

[image]

Here's my part of my code:

```
//Create Copy of Canvas
var copyOfContext = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
copyOfContext.canvas.width = c.width;
copyOfContext.canvas.height = c.height;
copyOfContext.fillStyle = "yellow";
copyOfContext.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
copyOfContext.putImageData(trimmedRect, 0, 0);

croppedImageURL = copyOfContext.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Edit: The reason I'm not doing it in my first canvas is bc I have a specific look for that to fit the webpage, so I'm using a second canvas to get the result and color I want. :)

Comment: `putImageData` ignores transparency and replaces all pixels with what is in the buffer. To copy one part of a canvas to another just use drawImage. `ctx1.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0)` Canvas is just an image and you can render it just like any other image. No need to get the pixelData

Comment: Thanks Blindman. I'm getting a type error when I pass trimmedRect in drawImage(). So trimmedRect is  essentially a rect I compute so I can only get the rect of the actual drawing so that i can place it in the center of the new canvas.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out a different way. I first place the image, then I fill the rectangle using `copyOfContext.globalCompositeOperation = "source-out";`. Not sure if there are any cons to that.

Comment: Where are you getting `trimmrdRect` from, use the canvas from that ctx to render. imageData is not an image, nor is the context, it is the canvas that needs to be drawn. With drawImage you can copy any region to any destination `ctx.drawImage(canvas,sx,sy,sw,sh,dx,dy,dw,dh)` where s is for source and d fir destination

Answer (score 1):

To copy from canvas to canvas just use `drawImage`.

The demo shows how it is done.

```js
var can1 = document.createElement("canvas");
var can2 = document.createElement("canvas");
can1.width = can2.width = 200;
can1.height = can2.height = 200;
can1.ctx = can1.getContext("2d");
can2.ctx = can2.getContext("2d");
can1.ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
can1.ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
can2.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
can2.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
can2.ctx.strokeRect(40,40,120,120);
document.body.appendChild(can1);
document.body.appendChild(can2);

can1.ctx.drawImage(can2,30,30,140,140,30,30,140,140);
```